# How good/bad is Zuko's vision?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

We all know about Zuko's scar.

[image: Zuko stands facing the viewer, looking slightly to the left. His right hand is on the side of his head, and a sword hilt is visible over his left shoulder. A purple blotch covers the top half of the left side of his face, starting just below the cheekbone and extending up under his hairline. The periorbital area is a darker purple, and his left eye is only open a mere slit.]

I have a pretty simple question I never thought about: can Zuko see out of his left eye?

You would think that he could, if only because it's never brought up in his fighting, but if not, how bad is his vision then?

Comment: I'm at a loss why someone would VTC as opinion-based.

Comment: What does VTC stand for?

Comment: Vote to Close...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per this AMA with the series creators, Zuko sees just fine out of both eyes.

> **Q: Is Zuko blind on his left side?**
>
> A: No, he can see out of that eye too. But I always imagined that his scar was very sensitive and painful, at least through his teenage years.
>
> <sub><sup>[Bryan and Mike's entire Q&A session from the Avatar Wiki](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheLastAirbender/comments/2k4yzy/all_spoilersbryan_and_mikes_entire_qa_session/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Ah, thank you for the info!